# 3 as a Sum of 3 Pan Digital Expressions

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

$Given$:

$3$  =  { A }  +  { B }  + { C }

Where A, B, C represent 3 unique Pan Digital Expressions.

Each contains all the digits 1 to 9 occurs  only once.

Expressions contain only plus, division signs . Left and Right brackets are present. No concatenations allowed.

Solve for A,B,C.

Comment: So we are only allowed to use + and $\div$?  Can we use parenthesis like $A=(1+2) \div 3$? Or implied parenthesis by $A=\frac{1+2}{3}$?

Comment: Can we concatenate for example use number $123$?

Comment: Is the usual BEDMAS order of operations assumed?

Comment: @Trennin..sure..that’s what I meant left and right brackets.  @weathervane..no concatenations allowed. All 3 expressions contain single digits 1 to 9, occurring only once....linked as needed by plus and division signs

Comment: As an example, one of the terms might look like...9/(1+6)

Comment: What is Bedmas order..to clarify even more..each expression has 3 terms

Comment: @Trennin with brackets [BODMAS](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html) won't matter.

Comment: Expressions should contain both plus and division signs..no other signs allowed

Comment: Again as an example..one of the terms can look like this...9/(8+7)..this can be linked with another term like that with a plus sign..so on

Comment: Yes..I stated that left and right brackets are present in the description.

Comment: Uvc, you might want to edit "no concatenations allowed" into the question body itself to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Sure..thx......

Comment: Posting my answer which is all fractional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - here is a real solution this time without concatenation.

I have a couple sub expressions.

> $x=\frac{2+3}{5}=1$
>  $y=\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4=1$

Now I can construct $A,B,C$.

> $$A=  1 \div \frac{\frac{2+3}{5}}{\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4}$$
>  $$B=  \frac{2+3}{5} \div \frac{1}{\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4}$$
>  $$C=  \frac{2+3}{5} \div \frac{\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4}{1}$$

Not sure if this is in the spirit of the puzzle since I am using the fact that $1 \div 1 = 1$ and getting a set of pan digital sub-expressions which equal to 1.

**EDIT:** I've added some other possibilities which don't bear as much resemblance to eachother.

> $$A=  1 \div \frac{\frac{2+3}{5}}{\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4}$$
>  $$B= \frac{5+\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4}{1+2+3}$$
>  $$C=\frac{9+8+7+1}{5} \div \frac{\frac{6}{3}}{4 \div 2}$$

Comment: I'd go for it, and call this a valid solution. Congrats!

Comment: As per puzzle, they all should be unique..you don’t have to use 1/1 trick..if nobody else comes close after few days, I will accept your answer...A, B, C as they stand now are just rearrangements

Comment: @Uvc Would you consider $\frac{5+\frac{9+8+7}{6} \div 4}{1+2+3}$ a different solution?

Comment: @Uvc Or how about $\frac{9+8+7+1}{5} \div \frac{\frac{6}{3}}{4 \div 2}$?

Comment: Sure..sufficiently different

Answer (score 4):

With pencil and paper:

> A. $ \frac{3}{9} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{ (4+8) / (5+7) }{2} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{2} = 1 $
>
>  B. $ \frac{1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5}{6 + 7 + 8 + 9} = \frac{15}{30} = \frac{1}{2} $
>
>  C. $ \frac{3 + 7 + 8 + 9}{1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 6} = \frac{27}{18} = \frac{3}{2} $
>
>  Sum: $ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = 3$

Comment: Very good one....

Comment: I was looking for three $1$s but got the last two fairly quickly when I looked for them. From $\sum_1^9 n = 45$.

Comment: For fun..this is the way to do

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

**EDIT:** Uses concatenations, so not a valid answer - sorry.

> $$A=\frac{\frac{7852}{1963}}{4}$$
>  $$B=\frac{\frac{6952}{1738}}{4}$$
>  $$C=\frac{\frac{5796}{483}}{12}$$

Comment: why the downvote? +1!

Comment: Quite clear - no concatentions.

Comment: @WeatherVane ARG - Didn't see that.... Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 2):

After wondering why people weren't doing very simple ones. I reread the rules realizing I misread the part where it says "Each contains all the digits 1 to 9 occurs only once."
after correcting my self, I came up with this:

> $$A = \frac{2+3+4+5+8}{6+7+9} \div 1 = \frac{22}{22} \div 1 = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$
>
>  $$B = \frac{\frac{1+8}{9}+7+6}{5+4+3+2} = \frac{\frac{9}{9}+13}{14} = \frac{1+13}{14} = \frac{14}{14} = 1$$
>
>  $$C = \frac{\frac{1+2}{3}+ \frac{4+5}{9}}{\frac{6+8}{7}} = \frac{\frac{3}{3} + \frac{9}{9}}{\frac{14}{7}} = \frac{1 + 1}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$$
>
>  Sum: 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, and thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Great effort!...once you realize that fractional route is better for this particular problem, solution becomes much neater..after you finish..you can look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Intended answer consists of 3 expressions with 3 fractions each:

> [image]